# TPM not working on compatible hardware

Tags: windows-10, tpm

I can't get TPM to be activated in Windows 10 on compatible hardware.

My specs:

- Asrock B550 ([declared compatible](https://www.asrock.com/support/faq.asp?id=500))
- AMD Ryzen 5 3600 ([declared compatible](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-11-supported-amd-processors))

What I already did:

- I changed my partition manager from MBR to GPT.
- I disabled CSM (switched to UEFI).
- I enabled Secure Boot.
- I changed the fTPM switch in UEFI under Advanced/CPU Configuration to AMD CPU TPM.

My problems:

- In UEFI under Advanced\Trusted Computing it says "No security device detected"
- In Windows under tpm.msc it says "No TPM (trusted platform module) found"

Both board and CPU are declared compatible by Microsoft. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Does your motherbaord have a TPM? Stupid question, but has to be asked. It may be that your motherboard only supports TPM1.2, but is installed with TPM2. You can downgrade the TPM firmware, but you'll have difficulty with Windows 11.

Comment: @Bib After working on this issue for an hour I was asking that myelf. It turned out that a BIOS update released only a few days ago is required to enable firmware based TPM (2.0). I left the instructions as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install the correct BIOS version for the Asrock B550 mainboard. My board came with BIOS version 1.80 which is unfit for TPM 2.0 support.

The version required is 1.90 which enables the use of fTPM (firmware based Trusted Platform Module) via the [Service page for the B550 boards](https://www.asrock.com/support/index.de.asp?Model=B550).

Instructions for updating the BIOS using Instant Flash can be found [here](https://www.asrock.com/support/BIOSIG.de.asp?cat=BIOS11).